# Difficulty using Diff on pandas date time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series in Pandas (dtype = datetime64) as follows:

```
timeSeries
35064   2013-11-11 16:44:26
35065   2013-11-11 17:37:15
35066   2013-11-11 18:30:03
35067   2013-11-11 19:22:51
35068   2013-11-11 20:15:39
```

If I then take the diff of this series:

```
diff_o_Series = diff(timeSeries)
```

I get the following results (dtype = timedelta64
):

```
diff_o_Series 
35064        NaT
35065   00:00:00
35066   00:00:00
35067   00:00:00
35068        NaT
```

Which is clearly NOT the delta differences between the times in the original array.  Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I believe OP meant [pandas.diff](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of `diff(timeSeries)`, use `timeSeries.diff()`

```
>> timeSeries
0   2013-11-11 16:44:26
1   2013-11-11 17:37:15
2   2013-11-11 18:30:03
3   2013-11-11 19:22:51
4   2013-11-11 20:15:39
dtype: datetime64[ns]

>> timeSeries.diff()
0        NaT
1   00:52:49
2   00:52:48
3   00:52:48
4   00:52:48
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `TimeSeries`, not `timeSeries`.

Comment: `timeSeries` was an instance of  `TimeSeries`, so it's `timeSeries`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `pandas`, what you should be typing is:

```
diff_o_Series = timeSeries.diff()
```

You were just ordering it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the difference of entire DataFrame (not just a series), you can use:

```
differenced_dataframe = yourDataframe.diff(axis = 0, interval = 1)
```

axis: you can specify if you want the different over rows (0) or columns (1)

interval: 1 is default, but you can specify periods to shift

For interval 1, your first row will be NaN, which should be removed before performing any further analysis/training.